# Equivalent of literal object in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm currently working on a website that is supposed to support multiple language. This website is developed thanks for Angular JS 1.4 and I'm currently working on upgrading it to Angular JS 2.0.

In the 1.x version, I have a global literal object that looks like this:

```
var language = {};
```

And then, I have several files that is doing something like this:

```
language.foo = {
   key_1: "value_1",
   key_2: "value_2",
   ...
   key_n: "value_n"
}
```

If I leave it like that, I can use it in my "ts" files like this:

```
var lang: string = language.foo.key_n;
```

It still works with AngularJS 2 but it is not very TypeScripty (besides, PHPStorm mark it as unknown). So what is the alternative to this global literal object in TypeScript ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use index signatures in the interfaces that describe the contents of `languages`:

```
// The top level object contains ILanguage objects, indexed by the name of the language.
interface ILanguages {
    [index: string]: ILanguage;
}

// An individual language contains strings, indexed by key name.
interface ILanguage {
    [index: string]: string;
}

// In the file where the language object is created:
var language: ILanguages = {};

// In the file where the foo language is defined:
language['foo'] = {
   key_1: "value_1",
   key_2: "value_2",
   ...
   key_n: "value_n"
}

// Everywhere else that it's just referenced:
declare var language: ILanguages;

var lang: string = language['foo']['key_1'];
```

This provides some structure and compile time checks for `languages` without having to define its fields explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to see if it suits me.

Answer (score -1):

In OOP you might use a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to solve something like this. This is just one option. [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is another good solution.